# Error while transforming in Python using rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I have bunch of NDWI files in a folder and I want to covert them into EPSG 4326. But it is giving error. Also, when I am printing the CRS of the source file, it is showing none. Is this the issue with the affine or something.

```
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling
    
dstSrc = {'init': 'EPSG:4326'}

srcPath = '/Users/admin/Downloads/Landsat8/NDWI/'
tifList = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(tifPath)) if f.endswith('.tif')]
print(tifList)
print(dstSrc)
Tif = rs.open(srcPath + tifList[0])
readTif = Tif.read(1)
print(Tif.crs) # crs:none
#Set destination path for the reprojected raster

dstPath = '/Users/admin/Downloads/Landsat8/NDWIrepro/'

#define function for the reprojection

def reprojection(srcRst, dstRst, dstSrc, srcPath, dstPath):
    srcRst = rs.open(srcPath + srcRst)
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(srcRst.crs, dstSrc, 
                                                          srcRst.width, srcRst.height, *srcRst.bounds)
#Copy the metadata

    kwargs = srcRst.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dstRst,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })
    dstRst = rs.open(dstPath + dstRst, 'w', **kwargs)
    
    for i in range(1, srcRst.count + 1):
        reproject(
            source = rs.band(srcRst, i),
            destination = rs.band(dstRst, i),
            src_crs = srcRst.crs,
            dst_crs = dstCrs,
            resampling = Resampling.nearest
        )
    dstRst.close()

for srcRst in tifList:
    dstRst = srcRst[:-4] + 'reprojected' + srcRst[-4:]
    reprojection(srcRst, dstRst, dstSrc, srcPath, dstPath)
    print(dstRst)
```

The error is

```
CPLE_AppDefinedError: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for <VRTDataset rasterYSize="7731" rasterXSize="7571"><VRTRasterBand /><SRS /><GeoTransform>0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0</GeoTransform></VRTDataset>. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
```

Comment: Edit your question to provide more details about your input raster, e.g. the output of `gdalinfo your_raster.tif` or `rio info your_raster.tif`. I assume from the error this will show your raster is not georeferenced.

Comment: I have mentioned that my_raster.tif.crs showing none when printed. I have edited accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Not having a CRS is different to not being georeferenced.